# Sort an editable ComboBox in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to sort an editable combobox in pure WPF, after the addition of a new record. After some research I found some tips, which used a `CollectionViewSource.SortDescription`, but it does not work for me correctly. What am I doing wrong? The DataContext of the item which used my `DataTemplate` works fine, but the binding between the `DataTemplate` and the resource part to sort my entry list doesn't.

---

**My XAML Part**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Document">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedLabels" Source="{Binding Parent.Labels}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Items"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>

    <Grid>
    ...
        <ComboBox Name="cbLabel"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedLabels}}"
                  IsEditable="True"
                  LostFocus="cbLabel_LostFocus"
                  KeyUp="cbLabel_KeyUp"
                  Visibility="{Binding Path=IsUndiscovered, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

**EDIT**
The Collection `Parent.Labels` are of type `ObservableCollection<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say since you didn't show what the collection is you're trying to sort, but my guess is that each object in Parent.Labels doesn't have a Items property. The PropertyName refers so a property on the individual objects in the list that it will look at and try to sort. I'd guess you want something more along the lines of "Name" or some other property.

Comment: It's a `ObservableCollection<String>`. I'm sorry that I forgot this information. I have added it.